# Is there an equivalent of .currentTime = 0 for phaser 3 audio?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a game in phaser 3 and I need to make it so that the music pauses and resets the time when you die, but I don't know if there's an equivalent of the audioObject.currentTime value for a phaser 3 audio object that can be used to restart audio, or something similar. Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Phaser 3 Audio object has all the property and method described [here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Sound.BaseSound.html)

You can play/pause/resume an audio, and you can access members like duration/totalDuration.